Liquibase with many includeAll and their chronology
I need to move some specific changeset file to another directory.
In the future, there are going to be new migrations added to both the directories.
Let's say the structure of firebase-related files under src/main/resources/db is going to be as follows:
.
├── changelog
│   └── db.changelog-master.yaml
├── migration
│   └── ... sql changesets ...
└── migration-specific
    └── ... sql changesets ...

with the db.changelog-master.yaml content:
databaseChangeLog:
  - includeAll:
      path: db/migration/
  - includeAll:
      path: db/migration-specific/

The problem here is the chronology of migration execution across the directories.
The naming convention is starting from date pattern and order number: YYYYMMDD_X_ - this should guarantee the right order of execution.
Despite that, liquibase runs every migration from one directory, then goes to the second one.
What I want to achieve is the shared chronology across the directories.
For example, given the filenames:
.
├── migration
│   ├── 20240501_1_...
│   └── 20240701_1_...
└── migration-specific
    └── 20240601_1_...

liquibase executes them in this order:
20240501_1_...
20240701_1_...
20240601_1_...

but I want it to be executed like this:
20240501_1_...
20240601_1_...
20240701_1_...

Is this achievable? If so - how?
Couple of information about the versions used:

liquibase-core: 4.17.0
spring boot: 2.7.18


Liquibase executes changeLogs in the order they are included in the master changeLog file (from top to bottom), so in your case order
20240501_1_...
20240701_1_...
20240601_1_...

is correct and expected.
There's no built-in mechanism for custom ordering.
The best approach I'd suggest is not to use includeAll.
Just use
<include file="migrations/20240501_...xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="migration-specific/20240601_...xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
<include file="migration/20240701_...xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

and you'll be fine.
It's not that hard to add each changeLog manually. This approach gives you the ordering control you need and makes sure that no changeLogs will be executed accidentally just by adding a file into /migrations directory.
